# Efficient FIFO queue for arbitrarily sized chunks of bytes in Python

Tags: python

How do I implement a FIFO buffer to which I can efficiently add arbitrarily sized chunks of bytes to the head and from which I can efficiently pop arbitrarily sized chunks of bytes from the tail?

Background:

I have a class that reads bytes from file-like objects in chunks of arbitrary size and is itself a file-like object from which clients can read the bytes in chunks of arbitrary size.

The way I have this implemented is that whenever a client wants to read a chunk of bytes, the class will repeatedly read from the underlying file-like objects (with chunk sizes appropriate to those objects) and add the bytes to the head of a FIFO queue until there are enough bytes in the queue to serve a chunk of the requested size to the client. It then pops those bytes off of the tail of the queue and returns them to the client.

I have a performance problem that occurs when the chunk size for the underlying file-like objects is much larger than the chunk size that clients use when reading from the class.

Say the chunk size for the underlying file-like objects is 1 MiB and the chunk size the client reads with is 1 KiB. The first time the client requests 1 KiB, the class has to read 1 MiB and add it to the FIFO queue. Then, for that request and the subsequent 1023 requests, the class has to pop 1 KiB from the tail of the FIFO queue, which gradually decreases in size from 1 MiB to 0 bytes, at which time the cycle starts again.

I have currently implemented this with a StringIO object. Writing new bytes to the end of the StringIO object is fast, but removing bytes from the beginning is very slow, because a new StringIO object, that holds a copy of the entire previous buffer minus the first chunk of bytes, must be created.

SO questions that deal with similar issues tend to point to the deque container. However, deque is implemented as as doubly linked list. Writing a chunk to the deque would require splitting the chunk into objects, each containing a single byte. The deque would then add two pointers to each object for storing, probably increasing the memory requirements by at least an order of magnitude as compared to the bytes. Also, it would take a long time to traverse the linked list and deal with each object both to split chunks into objects and to join objects into chunks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I have currently implemented this with a StringIO object. Writing new
>   bytes to the end of the StringIO object is fast, but removing bytes
>   from the beginning is very slow, because a new StringIO object, that
>   holds a copy of the entire previous buffer minus the first chunk of
>   bytes, must be created.

Actually the most typical way of implementing FIFO is two use wrap around buffer with two pointers as such:

[image] *[image source](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/embed/chap7/chap7.htm#FIFO)*

Now, you can implement that with `StringIO()` using [`.seek()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to read/write from appropriate location.

Comment: Ooh, +1 for the wraparound. I hadn't thought of that. You'd need to know the maximum size in advance though; actually, I suppose it could be grown as needed...

Comment: Thanks! This looks perfect. I did an experiment with StringIO that indicates that it will expand automatically to accommodate this. For instance, if the current size of the StringIO object is 10 bytes and PUTPT (the seek location) is at index 5, writing a 20 byte chunk automatically expands the StringIO object to 25 bytes, preserving the first 5 bytes and overwriting the rest. Though, if GETPT is currently after PUTPT, some more logic is required.

Comment: I've implemented this idea in my answer below. Cheers!

Answer (score 13):

> ... but removing bytes from the beginning is very slow, because a new StringIO object, that holds a copy of the entire previous buffer minus the first chunk of bytes, must be created.

This type of slowness can be overcome by using `bytearray` in Python>=v3.4. 
See discussion in this [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue19087) and the patch is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/5df8a8a1fd6cc6f4469dc7d3994d06e2aea24c52).

The key is: removing head byte(s) from `bytearray` by

```
a[:1] = b''   # O(1) (amortized)
```

is much faster than

```
a = a[1:]     # O(len(a))
```

when `len(a)` is huge (say 10**6).

The `bytearray` also provides you a convenient way to preview the whole data set as an array (i.e. itself), in contrast to deque container which needs to join objects into a chunk.

Now an efficient FIFO can be implemented as follow

```
class byteFIFO:
    """ byte FIFO buffer """
    def __init__(self):
        self._buf = bytearray()

    def put(self, data):
        self._buf.extend(data)

    def get(self, size):
        data = self._buf[:size]
        # The fast delete syntax
        self._buf[:size] = b''
        return data

    def peek(self, size):
        return self._buf[:size]

    def getvalue(self):
        # peek with no copy
        return self._buf

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._buf)
```

Benchmark

```
import time
bfifo = byteFIFO()
bfifo.put(b'a'*1000000)        # a very long array
t0 = time.time()
for k in range(1000000):
    d = bfifo.get(4)           # "pop" from head
    bfifo.put(d)               # "push" in tail
print('t = ', time.time()-t0)  # t = 0.897 on my machine
```

The circular/ring buffer implementation in Cameron's answer needs 2.378 sec, and his/her original implementation needs 1.108 sec.

Comment: it's also possible to use `del`, like so: `del self._buf[:size]` to use the fast delete syntax

Answer (score 12):

**Update**: Here's an implementation of the circular buffer technique from [vartec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10917913/21475) (building on my original answer, preserved below for those curious):

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

class FifoFileBuffer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buf = StringIO()
        self.available = 0    # Bytes available for reading
        self.size = 0
        self.write_fp = 0

    def read(self, size = None):
        """Reads size bytes from buffer"""
        if size is None or size > self.available:
            size = self.available
        size = max(size, 0)

        result = self.buf.read(size)
        self.available -= size

        if len(result) < size:
            self.buf.seek(0)
            result += self.buf.read(size - len(result))

        return result


    def write(self, data):
        """Appends data to buffer"""
        if self.size < self.available + len(data):
            # Expand buffer
            new_buf = StringIO()
            new_buf.write(self.read())
            self.write_fp = self.available = new_buf.tell()
            read_fp = 0
            while self.size <= self.available + len(data):
                self.size = max(self.size, 1024) * 2
            new_buf.write('0' * (self.size - self.write_fp))
            self.buf = new_buf
        else:
            read_fp = self.buf.tell()

        self.buf.seek(self.write_fp)
        written = self.size - self.write_fp
        self.buf.write(data[:written])
        self.write_fp += len(data)
        self.available += len(data)
        if written < len(data):
            self.write_fp -= self.size
            self.buf.seek(0)
            self.buf.write(data[written:])
        self.buf.seek(read_fp)
```

---

Original answer (superseded by the one above):

You can use a buffer and track the start index (read file pointer), occasionally compacting it when it gets too large (this should yield pretty good amortized performance).

For example, wrap a StringIO object like so:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
class FifoBuffer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buf = StringIO()

    def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Reads data from buffer"""
        self.buf.read(*args, **kwargs)

    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Appends data to buffer"""
        current_read_fp = self.buf.tell()
        if current_read_fp > 10 * 1024 * 1024:
            # Buffer is holding 10MB of used data, time to compact
            new_buf = StringIO()
            new_buf.write(self.buf.read())
            self.buf = new_buf
            current_read_fp = 0

        self.buf.seek(0, 2)    # Seek to end
        self.buf.write(*args, **kwargs)

        self.buf.seek(current_read_fp)
```

Comment: +1 This is awesome. Thank you for the complete implementation.

Comment: @Roger: No problem. I figured it might come in handy some day ;-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it any faster?

Comment: @Zamfir: No idea :-) Try it out and see?

Answer (score 4):

Can you assume *anything* about the expected read/write amounts?

Chunking the data into, for example, 1024 byte fragments and using `deque`[1] might then work better; you could just read N full chunks, then one last chunk to split and put the remainder back on the start of the queue.

1) [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#deque-objects)

`class collections.deque([iterable[, maxlen]])`

> Returns a new deque object initialized left-to-right (using append()) with data from iterable. If iterable is not specified, the new deque is empty.
>
> Deques are a generalization of stacks and queues (the name is pronounced “deck” and is short for “double-ended queue”). Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction. ...