# Howto emulate pipe-like buffer in Python?

Tags: python, pipe, stringio

Is there a way to use `StringIO` buffer like pipe with lazy write? Is there a way to hook a function to be called when End Of File/String occurs on the StringIO object to append next lines that can be read? Already read lines should by disposed.

Or is available another object/library like StringIO? I don't want to use the operating system pipes and forking. I need to foist a file-like buffer to [`psycopg2.copy_from()`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) but with behaviour like pipe.

Something like [Efficient FIFO queue for arbitrarily sized chunks of bytes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917581/efficient-fifo-queue-for-arbitrarily-sized-chunks-of-bytes-in-python) and [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects) but line oriented.